# NTILE function not working in Spark SQL 1.5

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, quantile

I'm testing the NTILE function on a simple dataset like this:

(id: string, value: double) 
A 10 
B 3 
C 4 
D 4 
E 4 
F 30 
C 30 
D 10 
A 4 
H 4

Running the following query against HIVE (on MapReduce)

```
SELECT tmp.id, tmp.sum_val, NTILE(4) OVER (ORDER BY tmp.sum_val) AS quartile FROM (SELECT id, sum(value) AS sum_val FROM testntile GROUP BY id) AS tmp
```

works fine with the following result:

(id, sum_val, quartile) 
B   3   1 
H   4   1 
E   4   2 
D   14  2 
A   14  3 
F   30  3 
C   34  4

Running the same query against Hive on Spark (v 1.5) still works fine.

Running the same query against Spark SQL 1.5 (CDH 5.5.1)

```
val result = sqlContext.sql("SELECT tmp.id, tmp.sum_val, NTILE(4) OVER (ORDER BY tmp.sum_val) AS quartile FROM (SELECT id, sum(value) AS sum_val FROM testntile GROUP BY id) AS tmp")
result.collect().foreach(println)
```

I get the following wrong result:

[B,3.0,0] 
[E,4.0,0] 
[H,4.0,0] 
[A,14.0,0] 
[D,14.0,0] 
[F,30.0,0] 
[C,34.0,0]

**IMPORTANT:** the result is NOT deterministic because "sometimes" correct values are returned

Running the same algorithm directly on the dataframe

```
val x = sqlContext.sql("select id, sum(value) as sum_val from testntile group by id")
val w = Window.partitionBy("id").orderBy("sum_val")
val resultDF = x.select( x("id"),x("sum_val"), ntile(4).over(w) )
```

still returns a wrong result.

Am I doing something wrong? Any ideas? Thanks in advance for your answers.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem. Regarding the last query on DataFrame it is not the same.

Comment: Hi, tnx for your reply. In the last example, I am not trying to execute exactly the same query. Instead I am trying to obtain the same result by means of the low level Spark Window functions introduced in version 1.4 (unfortunately the final result is wrong also in this  case :-/).

Answer (score 1):

If you use `Window.partitionBy("id").orderBy("sum_val")` you are grouping by `id` and after you are applying `ntile` function. So in this way every group has one element and `ntile` apply the same value for every `id`.

In order to achieve your first result, you need to remove `partitionBy("id")` and use only `Window.orderBy("sum_val")`.

This is how I modify your code:

```
val w = Window.orderBy("sum_val")
val resultDF = x.orderBy("sum_val").select( x("id"),x("sum_val"), ntile(4).over(w) )
```

And this is the print of `resultDF.show()`:

`+---+-------+-----+
| id|sum_val|ntile|
+---+-------+-----+
|  B|      3|    1|
|  E|      4|    1|
|  H|      4|    2|
|  D|     14|    2|
|  A|     14|    3|
|  F|     30|    3|
|  C|     34|    4|
+---+-------+-----+`